# Can I run a Qt application in initrd when the linux startup?

Tags: linux, qt, initrd

I wonder that if I can run a Qt application in **initrd** between the grub and the real os startup. And **stop** when the Qt application run.

Comment: I've heard about a thing 'boot-to-qt' that replaces the entire OS.

Comment: *Boot to Qt* does not replace any OS, but sits on top of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can do it since initrd itself is also an mini root system. however, compared to normal root system,   A lot of libraries aren't included in initrd to keep the size reasonable. so you have to add all the libraries needed by your  QT program yourself.or you can compile a static linked QT program which is a little more simple than dynamic ones.